# Shouldn't there be "loath" instead of "loathe" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> As an "iron brother", China would have been loathe to let Pakistan down and endorse India's claim that Pakistan was complicit in the attack.

No dictionary define "loathe" as an adjective or noun. And it was "loath" which was adjective, so I think "loath" should have been there instead of "loathe". Could anyone confirm it?

Comment: It's an error. Loathe is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct word would be *loath* (adj.).

The word *loathe* is the verb form, i.e. *to loathe < something/someone >*.

> I loathe
>   You loathe
>   He/She loathes
>   We loathe
>   They loathe

The adjective *loath* is what would have been correct in that text.

> As an "iron brother", China would have been ***loath*** to let Pakistan down and endorse India's claim that Pakistan was complicit in the attack.

I am not loath to criticise errors made in spelling and grammar by professional writers.